# Third Party php Library not loading in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, encryption, encoding

I am using codeigniter for my app. I want to hash my Database ids. For that  Reason am using the following php library: [HashIds for php](https://github.com/ivanakimov/hashids.php)

This library is in application/libraries/hashids.php

Here is my Controller code. I have tried different ways like Filename Uppercase and all that but it says unable to load the requested class

```
<?php 
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
//require_once(APPPATH.'');
//require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/hashids.php-master/src/Hashids.php');


class Pages extends CI_Controller {
  public function __construct() {

    parent::__construct();

    // include APPPATH . 'libraries/Hashids/Src/HashidsInterface.php';
    //include APPPATH . 'libraries/Hashids/Src/Hashids.php';

    //require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/Hashids/Src/HashidsInterface.php');
    require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/Hashids/Src/Hashids.php');

    //use Hashids/Src/Hashids.php;

    $this->load->model('post_model');
    $this->load->model('comment_model');
    $this->load->model('media_model');
    //$this->load->library('Hashids');
  }


  public function postFunc() {

    $this->load->library('hashids');  
    //$hashids = new hashids(); 

    $hashids->encode(1);
    echo $hashids;
    exit(); 
  }
```

The  above mentioned library also implements interface for that as I am new to codeigniter so don't know why is throwing error.

Comment: Have you followed the correct class naming conventions? - https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html#naming-conventions

Comment: Why don't you just add it with composer? That takes care of all the autoloading and stuff.

Comment: pls read how to load and create library : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html

Comment: You don't show how you're trying to load the library. Via config, or manually? Please show that code.

Comment: well what if i dont want to  add it with composer . is there anyother way of doing it

Answer (score 0):

Try using composer, I think it will be easier now and in the future to use libraries. [See here how to install composer.](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md)

First execute the command `composer require hashids/hashids` or add the lib to the `composer.json` file in the require object, like bellow, and execute the command `composer install`.

```
{
    "description": "The CodeIgniter framework",
    "name": "codeigniter/framework",
    "type": "project",
    "homepage": "https://codeigniter.com",
    "license": "MIT",
    "support": {
        "forum": "http://forum.codeigniter.com/",
        "wiki": "https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki",
        "slack": "https://codeigniterchat.slack.com",
        "source": "https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter"
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.7",
        "hashids/hashids": "3.0.0"
    },
    "suggest": {
        "paragonie/random_compat": "Provides better randomness in PHP 5.x"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "mikey179/vfsStream": "1.1.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.* || 5.*"
    }
}
```

In the configuration file `application/config/config.php` make sure you set the path to the composer autoloading script, like this:

```
$config['composer_autoload'] = 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

Usually the `autoload.php` file is inside the `vendor` folder that is created on the project root folder.

Then in your code try using the lib specifing the namespace `use Hashids\Hashids;` on top of the script like this:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

  use Hashids\Hashids;    

  class Pages extends CI_Controller {

      public function __construct() {        
          parent::__construct();

          $hashids = new Hashids(); // use the lib

          $this->load->model('post_model');
          $this->load->model('comment_model');
          $this->load->model('media_model');
          //$this->load->library('Hashids');        
      }
```

Comment: actually the thing is that  my website is online  and  i have  FTP credentials  so  how  can i install composer on  online Server

Comment: @user9496246 if you don't have access to a terminal I think you can't use composer. You can try to run the project locally and then update using FTP

Comment: thanks for the help  but  somehow  i  think that  this  issue  is  that    the  HASHIDs class uses  interface  to implement its function  so  may  be that  why  its not  loading the  class